# installed ghc from PPA 'no such file or directory'

Tags: haskell, ubuntu-14.04, ghc

I added GHC-7.10.1 from this `ppa:hvr/ghc` @ https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc

However I can't seem to find ghc from the command line.  any suggestions?

```
me@ubuntu:~/Documents/haskell$ ghc
bash: /usr/bin/ghc: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The *very place you linked to* explicitly says: "The packages install into `/opt/ghc/$VER/` so in order to use them, the easiest way is to bring a particular GHC version into scope by placing the respective `/opt/ghc/$VER/bin` folder early into the PATH environment variable." Well then, is /opt/ghc/$VER/bin in your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

As the linked page describes

> The packages install into `/opt/ghc/$VER/` so in order to use them, the easiest way is to bring a particular GHC version into scope by placing the respective `/opt/ghc/$VER/bin` folder early into the PATH environment variable.